# SQL Select multiple counts based on same WHERE clause

Tags: sql, select

Have data in my table like this:

```
Number  Date
18-000  2018-01-05  
18-001  2018-01-08
.......
Number  Date
19-350  2019-01-22
19-351  2019-01-22
19-352  2019-01-22
........
Number  Date
20-649  2020-01-24
20-650  2020-01-27
```

So the 2 digits in front of every number are indicating the year. I want to be able to count through all rows how many are starting with 18, 19 and 20 (separated). I did it for 18 and it is:

```
SELECT COUNT(Number) totalSUM
FROM my_table
where Number like N'18-%'
```

but how I can get returned 3 rows each with totalSUM for the year?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply take the left 2 characters of the `Number` column and group by that:

```
SELECT LEFT(Number, 2) AS year,
       COUNT(Number) AS totalSUM
FROM my_table
GROUP BY LEFT(Number, 2)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
year    totalSUM
18      2
19      3
20      2
```

[MySQL demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x7zCMYyPWHKEszUP9AGZtN/0)

[SQL Server demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d022205308dc73ddd6b3d096e4cee1c4)

Answer (score 2):

In case the number left of the dash has a variable length (e.g. 1-, 10-, 100-):

MySQL:

```
SELECT LEFT(number, LOCATE('-', number) - 1), COUNT(*)
FROM @t
GROUP BY LEFT(number, LOCATE('-', number) - 1)
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT LEFT(number, CHARINDEX('-', number) - 1), COUNT(*)
FROM @t
GROUP BY LEFT(number, CHARINDEX('-', number) - 1)
```